# Exported function not exported correctly

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I am developing an R package (let's call it `pkg`), and I have defined a few generics. The NAMESPACE file contains both

```
S3method(foo, bar)
export(foo)
```

However, upon calling `pkg::foo.bar`, I get the dreaded

> Error: 'foo.bar' is not an exported object from 'namespace:pkg'

I am using roxygen2, if that changes anything.

**Note:** If I explicitly add `export(foo.bar)`, then everything works.

Comment: if you use `devtools`, `@export` for all generic/methods? it always [worked fine](https://github.com/vbonhomme/Momocs/blob/master/R/core-out-efourier.R) for me (more doc [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#exports). Is `foo` a method you created or do you extend one ?

Comment: Yes, all generics are exported.`foo` is a method that I created, and is being called from another package I am writing (e.g. `secondPkg` imports `pkg` and is trying to call `pkg::foo.bar`).

Comment: I had same problem...many expletives later I discovered that NAMESPACE (and thus exports) is **only** updated when you run devtools::document() - not devtools::build() or devtools::install()

Comment: @virgesmith: This solved my problem too. Please consider writing an answer.

Answer (score 3):

NAMESPACE (and thus exports) is only updated when you run `devtools::document()` - not `devtools::build()` or `devtools::install()`.